# Why $\Bbb Z[x]/(p,x^2＋1)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb F_p[x]/(x^2＋1)$ as a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-fields

Could you tell me why $\Bbb Z[x]/(p,x^2＋1)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb F_p[x]/(x^2＋1)$ as a ring ?

I often uses this, but if I am asked why this holds, I'm stuck to explain..

How do you explain this isomorphism?

I'm looking forward your ideas.

Thank you in advance.

P.S Sorry, I corrected the typo.

Comment: Did you mean $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^2+1)$, i.e., without the extra $p$ in the quotient?

Comment: I think you're right @DerekAllums but of course it's the same thing as $p=0$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$.

Comment: You can first forget about $x^2+1$. It is just the fact that $\Bbb Z[x]/(p)\cong  (\Bbb Z/p)[x]=\Bbb F_p[x]$. Then of course $\Bbb Z[x]/(p,x^2+1)\cong  \Bbb F_p[x]/(x^2+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Define the following map:
$$\phi: \mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+1)\rightarrow \mathbb Z_p[x]/(x^2+1)$$
$$\phi([q(x)])=[q(x) \text{ mod p}]$$
This map is clearly a surjective ring homomorphism. As for the kernel:
$$\phi([q(x)])=0\iff q(x)=0\text{ mod p }\iff q(x)=p\cdot r(x)$$
Where $r$ is some polynomial. So the kernel is the ideal $(p)$. By the first isomorphism theorem:
$$(\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+1))/(p) \cong \mathbb Z_p[x]/(x^2+1)$$
But since $gcd(p,x^2+1)=1$, then by the third isomorphism theorem we have that:
$$\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+1,p) \cong (\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+1))/((x^2+1,p)/(x^2+1))\cong (\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+1,p))/(p)$$
Where in the last move you use the fact that $gcd(p,x^2+1)=1$ (try to see why :-).